Had or have in this case
In a podcast I heard this  "have you ever heard of the Gobs before this   " and the answer "I had not but I loved going ....." I am wondering why the answer was not "I have not"
But I am not sure of what I heard may be it was I have not .Anyway I found "had not" strange. Does it mean I had not heard it until you made me listen to it while we were preparing the program
punk this week podcast 01: fake fruit & melt-banana
Welcome to see/saw’s new podcast Punk This Week, co-hosted by Evan Minsker and Nina Corcoran
Gobs is a punk band

There's absolutely no way I'm going to locate a podcast and listen to the entire episode to get more context. But I strongly suspect the mistake was in the question, not the answer. It seems as if the "this" in "before this" was a past event. If that's true, "Had you ever heard" would have made more sense. But see https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/356605/138287: Don't worry about small mistakes in spoken audio where the meaning is clear. In fact, I would recommend, "don't even try to learn from them"; it more often just confuses one.

no it was not a past event it  was the current event the program

Then edit to give more context.

I’m voting to close this question because this question is based on reported speech where minor errors of grammar often occur.

just would like to know if HAD NOT  could be grammatical with a question beginning with  "HAVE YOU EVER HEARD" that 's all

It is switching tenses if you say "I had not heard" when asked "have you heard?" But it's perfectly understandable, and it makes sense in the construction, "I had not heard -- before now/this/your question."

Yes. Have you ever x? No, I had not until you said it!
